# Add a git configuration, that will run --no-verify automatically

Tags: git

I need to append a "--no-verify" flag, each time I run "git commit -m". I would like to somehow make this default behavior, being that I can forget the flag.

Is there some way to "intercept" the git commit command and append flags to it, in a repository?

Comment: What about adding a git alias (or bash alias) which does this?

Comment: Can you give an example to how that looks like? I mean, my idea is not to create a new command, but rather to change the behavior of the existing command. Remember that we type "git commit" as a habit :-)

Comment: I don't think you can use `git commit`. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases `git config alias.myCommand '-m --no-verify'`

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: This is why tools like [commitizen](https://commitizen-tools.github.io/commitizen/) exist

Comment: @i.brod If you always want `--no-verify` why do you have `pre-commit` hook at all?

Comment: Because we have some inconsistency in the way some pre-commit hook works. Until we resolve this issue, we would like to just disable it locally for me.

Comment: In bash, you can make a function named `git` that inspects options and arguments until it finds the command word. If the command word is `commit`, the function runs instead `command git ${preargs[@]} my-workaround-commit $@`, say; otherwise it runs `command git ${preargs[@]} $verb "$@"`. That way you can continue to type in `git commit`. Or you can just retrain your fingers.

Comment: Note that writing this function is a [Small Matter of Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming). Above, I assume the function saves each pre-command option (such as `-C <dir>`) in a bash array named `preargs`. Getting this right is tricky. Retraining your fingers is probably easier.

Comment: @i.brod "*…we would like to just disable it locally for me.*" Then disable it in `.git/hooks/`. Rename `pre-commit` to `pre-commit.backup`. When you want to restore it rename it back.

Comment: @phd This seems like a great solution